# EF generating query with invalid column resulting in PostgresException "column does not exist"

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

Trying to do a basic one-to-many relationship but getting the below error. It's adding another `accountstatusid` column in the query but the duplicate has an additional `1` at the end.

Error:
`Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column a.accountstatusid1 does not exist`

**Generated Query**

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.accountstatusid, a.accountstatusid1, a.name
FROM account AS a  
WHERE a.accountid = @__accountId_0  
LIMIT 2
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE accountstatus
(
    accountstatusid smallint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT accountstatus_pkey PRIMARY KEY (accountstatusid)
)

CREATE TABLE account
(
    accountid integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    accountstatusid smallint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (accountid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_accountstatusidid FOREIGN KEY (accountstatusid)
)
```

**Models**

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short AccountStatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
}

public class AccountStatus
{
    public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**DataContext**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AccountStatus> AccountStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountStatus>().ToTable("accountstatus");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(x => 
        {
            x.ToTable("account");
            x.HasOne(x => x.AccountStatus);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `AccountStatus` has `Key` of type `int` and your foreign key(`Account.AccountStatusId`) is of type `short` and the EF is not recognized `Account.AccountStatusId` as a foreign key to `AccountStatus` table and creates a new field.

If this won`t help you could try to set up a foreign key inside your model configuration.